# Is "bin" in bash script on Mac a reserved word?

Tags: bash, macos, bin

On my Mac I have two folders "bin" and "content" in a folder called "test".

In the "bin" folder I have the git binary from Xcode called "git_xcode13".

And I have an executable file called "test" in the "bin" folder with following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
cd "${DIR}/../content"
../bin/git_xcode13 clone https://github.com/aronsommer/altstadtwinterthur.git
```

My script does not work when using

```
../bin/git_xcode13 clone https://github.com/aronsommer/altstadtwinterthur.git
```

But it is working when I use

```
../Bin/git_xcode13 clone https://github.com/aronsommer/altstadtwinterthur.git
```

My folder is called "bin" but it gives me following

```
warning: templates not found in /Users/aronsommer/Desktop/share/git-core/templates
git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Does this mean that `../bin` is pointing to the standard "bin" folder instead to my "bin" folder on my desktop? Or has it to do with the git binary of Xcode?

[image]

Comment: Is your Mac filesystem case sensitive?

Comment: ^ Mac filesystem is case sensitive. Rename `Bin` to `bin` or use `Bin`

Comment: My folder is already called `bin`. But my script is only working when I use `Bin`. When I use `bin` in my script it does not work.

Comment: Does not make sense, it should be the other way around.  Can you show us the actual directory `ls`, and execution of your script please?

Comment: I have posted a screenshot above